# Не вставляется код в страницу

Tags: javascript

Не вставляется код в страницу.

```js
  function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  for(var key in attrs) {
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
}
      var p = document.createElement("p");
   var font = document.createElement("font");
   var b = document.createElement("b");
   setAttributes(font, {"size": "6", "color": "red"});
        b.innerHTML = "TEXT";
    my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1");
    document.body.insertBefore(p, font, b, my_div);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Во-первых, на странице нет элемента `org_div1`. Во-вторых, почитайте документацию по `insertBefore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У метода `insertBefore` два параметра:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

```js
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  for (var key in attrs) {
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
}
//var p = document.createElement("p");
var font = document.createElement("font");
var b = document.createElement("b");
setAttributes(font, {
  "size": "6",
  "color": "red"
});
b.innerHTML = "TEXT";
font.appendChild(b);

var my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1");
my_div.parentNode.insertBefore(font, my_div);
```

```html
<div id="org_div1">org_div1</div>
```

Comment: Текст должен быть красным.

Comment: @kazio Не возражаю.